# Intent-filter - Open NEW application, not embedded one

Tags: android, android-intent, task, intentfilter

I don't know if it's really understandable.

When i'm clicking on a llink in a mail, I can open this link with my application and that's perfeclty what I want.

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xxx.xxx.com"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

**BUT**

When i'm opening my application like that, and I check the opened application, I see that my application is "inside" Gmail task, like that

[image]

But, when i'm opening the link with Chrome for exemple, Chrome is opening in his own task, like that

[image]

How can my application open in her own task and **NOT** inside Gmail's one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set a specific [andorid:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) to your activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

or

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

placed in the declaration of your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml will do it.

take a look also at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks) article that explain how android handles tasks and activities

Comment: Oh right, I just see that i haven't add any launchmode  yet.
I'm trying it and re-commenting after thanks